# Python Flask generate whitespaces when when using template inheritance

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2

I am using Python 3.6 and Python flask to create a website. I am having a problem with the HTML template inheritance.

Parent File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="description" content="QuizBowl Practice Tool" />
    <meta name="keywoards" content="Altamont, Scholars Bowl, Learn, Enliten,Practice Tool" />
    <meta name="author" content="Henry the Dinosaur" />
    <title>Enliten | Welcome</title>
    <!-- Create a static/styles/base.css?q=1280549787 folder next to template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/base.css?q=1280549787" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    {% block script %} {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="Logo">
                <h1>Enliten</h1>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <!-- Links to Login and Practice and stuff-->
                <ul>
                    <li class="current"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="current"><a href="Question">Question Room</a></li>
                    <li class="current"><a href="Practice">Practice</a></li>
                    <li class="current"><a href="Profile">Profile</a></li>
                    <li class="current"><a href="Login">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
    <footer>
        <p>I will eat you if you try to copy this. Copyright &copy; 2018</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Child :

```
{% extends 'test.html'%}
```

The current issue is the parent HTML code will display the HTML code with the appropriate CSS without issue. However, the Child file creates a white bar on the top of the browser. I tried changing the CSS file, however, I later realized it wasn't an issue because the whitespace still exists when I load solely the HTML code.

CSS CODE

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #777;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.container{
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

header{
    background:#DEEBED;
    color:#777;
    min-height:70px;
    border-bottom:#ffffff 3px solid;
}

header a{
    color:#777;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size: 16px;

}
header ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}

header li{
    float:left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #Logo{
    float:left;
}

header #Logo h1{
    margin-top:10px;
}

header nav{
    float:right;
    margin-top:25px;
}

header .current a{
    color:#777;
    font-weight:bold;
}
footer {
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #777;
    background-color: #DEEBED;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `margin: 0` to `body`? If you still have the issue after that, you'll probably need to post your CSS as well.

Comment: Yes, tried changing the margin:0; in body for the CSS. It only causes it go to the top until the white bar.

Answer (score 0):

I know this comes very late but, if anyone else stumbles onto the same issue, here's what I found :
I used msvc to create the template file, it saved it using UTF-8 with signature (default encoding).
Saving the file using UTF-8 with no signature solved the issue.